# CodeIgniter + Ion Auth: Ion Auth config file is loaded twice

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Explanation:

Using CodeIgniter v3.1.2 with Ion Auth 2

I separated the admin area and user area into 2 different applications to improve security.

I wanted to share config files between two apps so for application_admin/config/ion_auth.php I did this:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../application_users/config/ion_auth.php');
```

The script stopped working and after some hours I realized the file is being loaded twice because when I use `require` instead of `require_once` everything work's fine.

### Questions:

1. Shouldn't CodeIgniter check and prevent loading files that are already loaded twice? if yes then why is this happening, and if not is it okay if I just use `require` instead of `require_once`?
2. Is my approach the correct way of sharing config files and helpers between multiple applications in a single CI install?

#### Edit:

I put the require_once in the `admin/config/ion_auth.php` to include `user/config/ion_auth.php` so basically I'm putting the content of that config file in this config file "only when CodeIgniter itself loads this config file".

Also even if I put the normal ion_auth config file without any require/include etc, it is still loaded twice (I noticed by putting a simple `echo 'loaded<br>';` in the end of config file.)

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't CodeIgniter check and prevent loading files that are already
>   loaded twice? if yes then why is this happening, and if not is it okay

By making direct call to `require` or `require_once` you are bypassing Codeigniter (CI) so it has no way of knowing what you have or have not included.

> if I just use require instead of require_once? Is my approach the
>   correct way of sharing config files and helpers between multiple
>   applications in a single CI install?

Loading a config file in CI should be done using the [Config class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html). If you dig into the source code for Ion Auth and look at `__construct` in `Ion-auth_model.php` you will find heavy use of the config class to read the config file and access various config items. It a good example of the "CI way" to handle configuration.

Comment: Thank you sir, but I put `require_once` in the `admin/config/ion_auth.php`  to include the exact same config from `user/config/ion_auth.php` so basically I'm putting the content of that file in here only when CodeIgniter itself has loaded this config file. Also even if I put the normal ion_auth config file without any modification, it is still loaded twice (I noticed by putting a simple `echo 'loaded<br>';` in this config file.